# Java, Rotating an image around itselft

Tags: java, image, swing, image-rotation

I know how to rotate an image in java, but I can't find a way to rotate an image around its center using the Graphics2D.rotate method. Here is what I have.

```
public void rotateLeft(Graphics2D g) {
    rotateLeft++;

    g.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotateLeft), charX, charY);
}
```

charX and charY are coordinates by the way... So, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
g.rotate(angle, (imageWidth / 2) + 1, (imageHeight / 2) + 1);
```

Comment: Assuming you are drawing your image in `(0,0)`

Comment: It didn't work... Also, I am moving my image around the screen, so the method has to be dynamic..

Comment: I have used this before many times. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing it:

```
        AffineTransform oldTrans = g2d.getTransform();
        g2d.rotate(-theta,xNow+bufferedBox.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight() - groundY - yNow - bufferedBox.getHeight()/2);
        g2d.drawImage(bufferedBox, xNow, this.getHeight() - groundY - yNow - bufferedBox.getHeight(), null);
        g2d.setTransform(oldTrans);
```

xNow an yNow are my coordinates where my box will be. "this" refers to the jPanel, groundY is the offset (it's on top of the ground). bufferedBox refers to my image